# How to call JavaScript function from with in Flash application?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

So in my AS file I want to call a function like

```
        public function JS(streamUri:String):void{
        JavascriptCommand(streamUri)
        }
```

to get my JS code running...

How to do such thing (Example needed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [ExternalInterface.call()](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#call()). [Adobe has an article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/external_interface_05.html) about how to use it to call JavaScript from ActionScript.

You can also use ExternalInterface to expose ActionScript to JavaScript and call functions internal to your SWF from JavaScript.

Let's say you have a JavaScript function that looks like this:

```
function specialAlert(msg) {
  alert(msg);
}
```

From your flash file you can call it like this:

```
import flash.external.*;

ExternalInterface.call("specialAlert", "Hi mom!");
```

And your JavaScript function should be called and alert the user "Hi mom!".

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to call JS from flex: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-javascript-basics-using-externalinterface

Comment: And Is there a way to send a full body of JS functions?